# Creating a Basecamp like website

Tags: laravel-5

I'm currently learning Laravel, I have started creating my own Basecamp like website (project management tool). So far i have the Home page / login page and Users dashboard all set up so when the user logs in they are navigated to their dashboard page,
when in the dashboard they will click a button named create project whihc pops up a modal with -> add project name on submit it will create a new project panel on the dashboard that shows the Project name and a view button that will then take them to their created project to start work.
however i'm unsure on how to set this up as i'm super new to laravel and still trying to get my head around it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would highly recommend starting off with a boiler plate project - this gives you a head start as well as teaches you best practices.

Example:
https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate

If your new to PHP then you could try:
https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager which creates the CRUD's for you. Going to be quicker to get up and running but I think it will hold you back when you project gets bigger.

Comment: this doesn't really help me im not looking for a admin panel like Voyager or using bolierplate

Comment: Then your question is unfortunately too broad.. you will not get any helpful answers. Try reformat your question to be more specific